# How can I use PHP to automatically change the page if

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, hyperlink

...the conditions of an if statement are fulfilled?

I have some code to add data to a database if certain conditions are met, after the data is added I want the page to redirect to another page? How can I do this?

Comment: `header('location: /page2.php');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use if-else condition. You can use header() of PHP .

```
if(/* Your conditions */){
// redirect if fulfilled
header("Location:nxtpage.php");
}else{
//some another operation you want
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shoul use header php function

```
<?php 

  //some conditions

  header("Location: http://www.example.com/");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
 $query ="insert into test values (1,'test')";

if(mysql_query($query) == true)
{
  header('location:index.php');
  exit();
}
else
{
  echo " insert failed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHP Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

header('Location: http://www.example.com/');